# How does one declare devices behind muxes in ACPI?

Tags: linux, acpi

I am trying to encode the following layout of devices in an ACPI table using ASL.

[image]

While the drivers for the muxes (and everything else directly under `\_SB_.PCI0.I2C1` and `\_SB_.PCI0.I2C2`) probe and work correctly (based on `i2cdetect -y -r MUX_CH_BUS 0x29 0x29`) but the devices behind the multiplexers will not probe.

I have been trying to follow [this example](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/firmware-guide/acpi/i2c-muxes.html), but I have a growing suspicion that it is untested nonsense, I mean, I'm pretty sure this would not even compile due to the missing `)` after the `_CRS` `name` block.

**Is it a problem that I have objects with the same name in different parts of my hierarchy?** From debugging (i.e., lots of `printk` inside of `i2c-core-acpi.c`) it seems that the ACPI code is only checking devices against `MUX0.CH00`. To work around this, I removed all the devices except one, leaving me with this ASL description:

```asl
Scope (\_SB_.PCI0.I2C1) {
    
    Device (MUX2)
    {
        Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
        Name (_DDN, "NXP PCA9544A I2C bus multiplexer")
        Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
            I2cSerialBus (
                0x72,
                ControllerInitiated,
                100000,
                AddressingMode7Bit, 
                "\\_SB.PCI0.I2C1",
                0x00,
                ResourceConsumer,,)
        })
        Name (_DSD, Package () {
            ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
            Package () {
                Package () {"compatible", "nxp,pca9544"},
            }
        })

        Device (CH00) {
            Name (_ADR, 0)
        }

        Device (CH01) {
            Name (_ADR, 1)
            Device (TOF1) {
                Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
                Name (_DDN, "STMicroelectronics VL53L0X laser rangefinder")
                Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                    I2cSerialBus (
                        0x29,
                        ControllerInitiated,
                        100000,
                        AddressingMode7Bit,
                        "\\_SB.PCI0.I2C1.MUX2.CH01",
                        0x00,
                        ResourceConsumer,,)
                })
                Name (_DSD, Package () {
                    ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                    Package () {
                        Package () {"compatible", "st,vl53l0x"},
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        
        Device (CH02) {
            Name (_ADR, 2)
        }
        
        Device (CH03) {
            Name (_ADR, 3)
        }
    }
}
```

I removed the `"^CH01"` and replaced it with `"\\_SB.PCI0.I2C1.MUX2.CH01"` instead since `"^CH01"` was failing on [this line in kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-acpi.c#L84). Unfortunately, this still does not result in the remaining single TOF sensor being probed.

I can confirm that in both the case with all muxes and TOF sensors and the case with a single mux and TOF sensor, I can find `PRP0001:XX` entries for both devices under `sys/bus/acpi/devices` with modalias's formed from the compatible property and device name.

Do I have a bug in my ASL or is it perhaps a limitation of ACPI in the Linux kernel where all device objects need unique names? Any suggestions on how to investigate this further would really be appreciated!

**UPDATE:** Added info as per the comments:

The debugging is simply tracing the function calls through *i2c-core-acpi.c*, for two devices (i) a USB hub on I2C1 (works correctly/probes) and (ii) a TOF sensor under one of the muxes.

The following patch is for kernel v5.2.32 and shows my tracing

```patch
diff --git a/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-acpi.c b/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-acpi.c
index 9a3bcfcad35f..c651e6032e84 100644
--- a/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-acpi.c
+++ b/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-acpi.c
@@ -15,6 +15,8 @@
 
 #include "i2c-core.h"
 
+bool i2c_acpi_trace = false;
+
 struct i2c_acpi_handler_data {
        struct acpi_connection_info info;
        struct i2c_adapter *adapter;
@@ -79,6 +81,10 @@ static int i2c_acpi_fill_info(struct acpi_resource *ares, void *data)
        if (info->addr || !i2c_acpi_get_i2c_resource(ares, &sb))
                return 1;
 
+       if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+               printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_fill_info: info->addr == 0 && resource != 0");
+       }
+
        if (lookup->index != -1 && lookup->n++ != lookup->index)
                return 1;
 
@@ -116,16 +122,33 @@ static int i2c_acpi_do_lookup(struct acpi_device *adev,
            acpi_device_enumerated(adev))
                return -EINVAL;
 
+       if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+               printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_lookup: state/present/enumerated");
+       }
+
        if (acpi_match_device_ids(adev, i2c_acpi_ignored_device_ids) == 0)
                return -ENODEV;
 
+       if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+               printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_lookup: acpi_match_device_ids");
+       }
+
        memset(info, 0, sizeof(*info));
        lookup->device_handle = acpi_device_handle(adev);
 
        /* Look up for I2cSerialBus resource */
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&resource_list);
+
        ret = acpi_dev_get_resources(adev, &resource_list,
                                     i2c_acpi_fill_info, lookup);
+
+       if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+               printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_lookup: acpi_dev_get_resources -> %d", ret);
+       }
+       if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+               printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_lookup: info->addr -> %x", info->addr);
+       }
+
        acpi_dev_free_resource_list(&resource_list);
 
        if (ret < 0 || !info->addr)
@@ -149,16 +172,28 @@ static int i2c_acpi_get_info(struct acpi_device *adev,
        lookup.index = -1;
 
        ret = i2c_acpi_do_lookup(adev, &lookup);
+       if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+               printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_get_info: i2c_acpi_do_lookup -> %d", ret);
+       }
+
        if (ret)
                return ret;
 
        if (adapter) {
                /* The adapter must match the one in I2cSerialBus() connector */
+               if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+                       printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_get_info: adapter != NULL");
+               }
                if (ACPI_HANDLE(&adapter->dev) != lookup.adapter_handle)
                        return -ENODEV;
+               if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+                       printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_get_info: adapter->dev == lookup.adapter_handle");
+               }
        } else {
                struct acpi_device *adapter_adev;
-
+               if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+                       printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_get_info: adapter == NULL");
+               }
                /* The adapter must be present */
                if (acpi_bus_get_device(lookup.adapter_handle, &adapter_adev))
                        return -ENODEV;
@@ -174,6 +209,11 @@ static int i2c_acpi_get_info(struct acpi_device *adev,
        /* Then fill IRQ number if any */
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&resource_list);
        ret = acpi_dev_get_resources(adev, &resource_list, NULL, NULL);
+
+       if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+               printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_get_info: acpi_dev_get_resources -> %d", ret);
+       }
+
        if (ret < 0)
                return -EINVAL;
 
@@ -213,11 +253,32 @@ static acpi_status i2c_acpi_add_device(acpi_handle handle, u32 level,
        struct i2c_adapter *adapter = data;
        struct acpi_device *adev;
        struct i2c_board_info info;
+       int ret = 0;
 
        if (acpi_bus_get_device(handle, &adev))
                return AE_OK;
 
-       if (i2c_acpi_get_info(adev, &info, adapter, NULL))
+       if(strcmp(acpi_dev_name(adev), "PRP0001:00") == 0 &&
+          strcmp(adapter->name, "Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter") == 0) {
+          printk(KERN_ERR "--- start trace for PRP0001:00 ---");
+          i2c_acpi_trace = true;
+       }
+
+       if(strcmp(acpi_dev_name(adev), "PRP0001:02") == 0 &&
+          strcmp(adapter->name, "i2c-0-mux (chan_id 1)") == 0) {
+          printk(KERN_ERR "--- start trace for PRP0001:02 ---");
+          i2c_acpi_trace = true;
+       }
+
+       ret = i2c_acpi_get_info(adev, &info, adapter, NULL);
+
+       if(i2c_acpi_trace) {
+               printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_acpi_get_info -> %d", ret);
+               printk(KERN_ERR "--- end trace ---");
+       }
+       i2c_acpi_trace = false;
+
+       if (ret)
                return AE_OK;
 
        i2c_acpi_register_device(adapter, adev, &info);
```

The output of this during boot for PRP0001:00 (USB hub) is:

```
--- start trace for PRP0001:00 ---
i2c_acpi_lookup: state/present/enumerated
i2c_acpi_lookup: acpi_match_device_ids
i2c_acpi_fill_info: info->addr == 0 && resource != 0
i2c_acpi_lookup: acpi_dev_get_resources -> 0
i2c_acpi_lookup: info->addr -> 8
i2c_acpi_get_info: i2c_acpi_do_lookup -> 0
i2c_acpi_get_info: adapter != NULL
i2c_acpi_get_info: adapter->dev == lookup.adapter_handle
i2c_acpi_get_info: acpi_dev_get_resources -> 0
i2c_acpi_get_info -> 0
--- end trace ---
```

And for PRP0001:02 (ToF sensor) is:

```
i2c i2c-0: Added multiplexed i2c bus 5
--- start trace for PRP0001:02 ---
i2c_acpi_lookup: state/present/enumerated
i2c_acpi_lookup: acpi_match_device_ids
i2c_acpi_fill_info: info->addr == 0 && resource != 0
i2c_acpi_lookup: acpi_dev_get_resources -> 0
i2c_acpi_lookup: info->addr -> 29
i2c_acpi_get_info: i2c_acpi_do_lookup -> 0
i2c_acpi_get_info: adapter != NULL
i2c_acpi_get_info: adapter->dev == lookup.adapter_handle
i2c_acpi_get_info: acpi_dev_get_resources -> 0
i2c_acpi_get_info -> 0
--- end trace ---
i2c i2c-0: Added multiplexed i2c bus 6
i2c i2c-0: Added multiplexed i2c bus 7
i2c i2c-0: Added multiplexed i2c bus 8
```

So in this constrained situation with a single mux, ToF sensor, and a hardcoded path (i.e., not using `"^CHXX"`) it seems that things are working correctly, with the exception that the driver for the ToF still isn't probing...

The output of `grep -H . /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP*/*` for the current configuration is:

```sh
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:00/hid:PRP0001
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:00/modalias:of:Nusb0TCsmsc,usb3503
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:00/path:\_SB_.PCI0.I2C1.USB0
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:00/uevent:MODALIAS=of:Nusb0TCsmsc,usb3503
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:01/hid:PRP0001
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:01/modalias:of:Nmux2TCnxp,pca9544
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:01/path:\_SB_.PCI0.I2C1.MUX2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:01/uevent:MODALIAS=of:Nmux2TCnxp,pca9544
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:02/hid:PRP0001
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:02/modalias:of:Ntof1TCst,vl53l0x
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:02/path:\_SB_.PCI0.I2C1.MUX2.CH01.TOF1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:02/uevent:MODALIAS=of:Ntof1TCst,vl53l0x
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:03/hid:PRP0001
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:03/modalias:of:Nioe0TCnxp,pca9554
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:03/path:\_SB_.PCI0.I2C2.IOE0
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:03/uevent:MODALIAS=of:Nioe0TCnxp,pca9554
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:04/hid:PRP0001
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:04/modalias:of:Nioe1TCnxp,pca9554
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:04/path:\_SB_.PCI0.I2C2.IOE1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:04/uevent:MODALIAS=of:Nioe1TCnxp,pca9554
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:05/hid:PRP0001
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:05/modalias:of:Nusb1TCsmsc,usb3503
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:05/path:\_SB_.PCI0.I2C2.USB1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:05/uevent:MODALIAS=of:Nusb1TCsmsc,usb3503
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:06/hid:PRP0001
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:06/modalias:of:NledcTCnxp,pca9635
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:06/path:\_SB_.PCI0.I2C2.LEDC
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001:06/uevent:MODALIAS=of:NledcTCnxp,pca9635
```

Output of `ls -l /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-6/`

```
--w-------    1 root     root          4096 Aug 20 15:10 delete_device
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Aug 20 15:10 device -> ../../i2c-0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Aug 20 15:10 firmware_node -> ../../../../LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/808622C1:00/PRP0001:01/device:3a
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root             0 Aug 20 15:00 i2c-PRP0001:02
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Aug 20 15:10 mux_device -> ../i2c-PRP0001:01
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Aug 20 15:10 name
--w-------    1 root     root          4096 Aug 20 15:10 new_device
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Aug 20 15:10 power
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Aug 20 15:00 subsystem -> ../../../../../bus/i2c
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Aug 20 15:00 uevent
```

Comment: Yeah, that ASL wasn’t tested, because ACPI support of PCA954x muxes appeared only in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/i2c/muxes/i2c-mux-pca954x.c?id=753aa3694382c5d967dcb427ae0c3ee199bd21aa or this year. Actually, with `CONFIG_OF=y` it might be possible, but still you are right about syntax errors in the excerpt.

Comment: @0andriy thanks for pointing out that patch, for the remainder of your questions, see the add content after **UPDATE**

Comment: I believe so, I am trying to follow the path now between when the device is registered and when probe is called to see if I can figure out where things are breaking...

Comment: Ok, things are breaking here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2.21/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-base.c#L345 although I'm not sure why yet. I could add a `acpi_match_table` but that doesn't seem right for PRP0001 devices, so I need to investigate why `i2c_of_match_device` is not returning a match...

Comment: The driver is compiled/built in and the output from sysfs has been added at the bottom of the question. Following `i2c_of_match_device` (which I think should be used for matching PRP0001 devices) it seems that it wants to match `dev->of_node` against the match table in the driver... no idea when/where/if `dev->of_node` is actually initialized though...

Comment: But do you have mux itself up and running? Can you show `ls -l /sys/bus/i2c/`? Can you show `i2cdetect -y -r ...` for the bus in question? `lsmod`? Seems like MUX is there and it sees the device. Can you `ls -l .../i2c-PRP0001:02`?

Comment: What `i2cdetect -l` shows? And what is the output of `dmesg | grep i2c`? Also `grep -H . /sys/bus/i2c/devices/*/name`

Comment: Yep, the mux is up and running. The sensors on the other side of the mux can be detected with `i2cdetect`. The problem is the matching: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2.21/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-base.c#L345

Comment: I moved this part of the question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519678/how-should-i2c-drivers-be-matched-in-acpi-with-hid-prp0001 since this is getting a bit off the topic from the question asked above