# How should I2C drivers be matched in ACPI with HID PRP0001

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, acpi

I am trying to instantiate [this sensor](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/drivers/iio/proximity/vl53l0x-i2c.c) in ACPI using device specific data, i.e., with `Name (_DSD, ...)` and with a compatible string, e.g., with the following ASL excerpt:

```c
Device (TOF1) {
    Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
    Name (_DDN, "STMicroelectronics VL53L0X laser rangefinder")
    Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
        I2cSerialBus (
            0x29,
            ControllerInitiated,
            I2C_SPEED,
            AddressingMode7Bit,
            "\\_SB.PCI0.I2C1.MUX2.CH01",
            0x00,
            ResourceConsumer,,)
    })
    Name (_DSD, Package () {
        ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
        Package () {
            Package () {"compatible", "st,vl53l0x"},
        }
    })
}
```

I was under the impression that if I specify my devices as I have in the above ASL, I would not need to modify the driver (e.g., by adding an ACPI match tables) and could match the device using the existing OF match table in the driver. However, this only seems partly true. The sensor fails to probe due to this check in the kernel in [i2c-core-base.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-base.c#L345):

```c
if (!driver->id_table &&
    !i2c_acpi_match_device(dev->driver->acpi_match_table, client) &&
    !i2c_of_match_device(dev->driver->of_match_table, client))
    return -ENODEV;
```

My interpretation of this statement is that the device driver must either have (i) an ID table or (ii) a matching ACPI ID table or (iii) a matching OF ID table. The VL53L0X does not have an ID table nor a ACPI match table, so I am relying on matching using the OF table.

Now, there are two things that I am confused about here. Firstly, I can `printk(KERN_ERR "%s", dev->driver->driver.name)` and see that I am indeed already looking at the correct driver, so why exactly are we checking if the driver matches again?

Secondly, if `i2c_of_match_device(dev->driver->of_match_table, client)` is failing to match, what exactly was matched in the first place that resulted in being able to `printk(KERN_ERR "%s", dev->driver->driver.name)` and see the correct name of the driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question above, but one hack/work around for this problem is to just add the ID table to the driver.

```c
static const struct i2c_device_id vl53l0x_id[] = {
    { "vl53l0x", 0 },
    { }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, vl53l0x_id);

static struct i2c_driver vl53l0x_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "vl53l0x-i2c",
        .of_match_table = st_vl53l0x_dt_match,
    },
    .probe_new = vl53l0x_probe,
    .id_table = vl53l0x_id,
};
module_i2c_driver(vl53l0x_driver);
```

This results in the check in the question being skipped over. This isn't a great solution since the I2C ID table is not passed to `probe_new`, however, it does work for this driver since there is no further configuration to be done.

It seems however that matching i2c devices like this is being deprecated as per the comments and patches around the introduction of `probe_new`.

Comment: You beat me up to it. Yes, adding ID table is the simplest way to mitigate this (btw, are you going to send this upstream? Please do!), but the real fix somewhere in between those lines you pointed out to. Also note, adding ID table not the bad idea even for `->probe_new()` drivers, i.o.w. it's **not** a bulk. User may enumerate device from userspace this way.

Comment: You may extend your answer in explaining why it works. So the `CONFIG_OF=n` in your case and thus OF match fails and since neither ACPI, nor ID table defined the rest all fails. This check should be revisited. I dunno what the logic behind checking explicitly for ACPI table in ACPI enabled environments w/o checking PRP0001 case.

Comment: You were right on the money when it came to `CONFIG_OF=n` on my system. If you want to add a quick answer, I will accept it as the answer to this question. It seems a bit strange that the  `CONFIG_OF=n` disables the functionality that PRP0001 devices need to match their DSD properties (especially the compatible string) against the `of_match_table`. Since PRP0001 devices are a thing, it seems that having ACPI support should automatically enable `CONFIG_OF` in KConfig...

Comment: `CONFIG_OF` here is a side thing. It doesn't affect PRP0001. There is simple a bug in the code.

Comment: I will try find time to do that today

Comment: I'm a little bit too busy at the moment, but I think I will put some time aside in a few weeks to test this and to submit some patches for a few other drivers that I have improved recently (i.e., mostly moving them to the unified device property API)...

Comment: In any case the patch is in upstream: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/wsa/linux.git/commit/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-base.c?h=i2c/for-next&id=e3cb82c6d6f6c27ab754e13ae29bdd6b949982e2.